# Content breaks when I minimize in IE6

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

I know that `IE6` is obsolete but my customer still uses IE6.
This project's content segment must be a percentage scale, but when the content's height is very long and user decides to minimize the browser, the content segment jumps to the bottom of side bar.

My code when `dashboard_content` with longer content

CSS code:

```
#outer-box {
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    float: right;
}

#inner-box-1 {
    width: 225px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color:#253740;
    float:right;
}

#inner-box-2 {
   height: 100%;
   direction: rtl;
   overflow:auto;
   *overflow: inherit;
}

.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: url('imgs/pattern.jpg') repeat-x;
}

.dashboard_main_menu_holder {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
}

.dashboard_content {
    width: 98%;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

HTML code:

```
<div id ="outer-box">
    <div id="inner-box-1">
        <div class="user_image"></div>
        </div>

    <div id="inner-box-2">
        <div class="header"></div>
        <div class="dashboard_main_menu_holder"></div>
        <div class="dashboard_content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can i get this fixed in IE6?

Comment: Why would you even want to support a 12 year old browser?

Comment: @PeteR it is in the first sentence, "customer still uses IE6"

Comment: Thanks David, I did see that. The point I was trying to make is that if you keep frigging valid code to run on buggy and obsolete browsers, then people will never upgrade. Several of my customers have upgraded based on recommendation + refusal to support old browsers (company policy). Harsh, I know, but you have to draw the line somewhere and 12 years is as good a time to start as any.

Comment: Definitely off-topic for this question, but @PeteR has a good point here. Requiring minimum specs from customers is not uncommon, and allows for much greater development. OP, you may want to consider bringing it up.

Comment: it's hard to help you unless installing a VM nowadays

Comment: I totally agree with @PeteR that we need to ask our customers to upgrade with their technologies to the latest updates to get things fast. I have never seen a people who are still using IE6 still. so sad :(.  If your customer is not listening to your words, then write a new css file and load that file if the browser is less than IE7 I mean try to load diff. css based on browser version.

Comment: Instead of using pixels use em, it is some kind of resizable font in all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Change the %s on the CSS to the amount of px. You can find more information on this [link](http://www.sitepoint.com/10-fixes-for-ie6-problems/).

Comment: tnx dear , but i must use percentage dimention for this project